# Why don't these lines have the same thickness? PIXI.JS

Tags: pixi.js

Let me ask you a question about PIXI.js. In Chrome, these lines looks like not the same thickness, but its the same Graphics API (lineTo, moveTo). Why is that?

[image: demo]

```
let boxW = 46.5;

this.leftBox
  .lineStyle(1, 0x000,1)
  .beginFill(0xffffff)
  .moveTo(0, 0)
  .lineTo(465, 0)
  .lineTo(465, 465) 
  .lineTo(0, 465)
  .lineTo(0, 0)
  .endFill();

for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
  this.leftBox.moveTo(boxW * i, 0).lineTo(boxW * i, 465);
}
```

Comment: Anti aliasing?  Try changing boxW to a whole number and see if that changes anything.  Otherwise look at the rest of your code (for anything that might cause scaling for instance) which we cant see.  A working online example of the problem is always appreciated.  OH and if boxW is at .5 then I think the moveTo/LineTo  cords should be aswell.

Comment: If you give me a working example at jsfiddle, plnkr, codepen, woteva, I WILL give you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PAEz is right, it is likely anti aliasing.

When you create you Application anti-aliasing is turned off by default.

Try the below and see if it helps:

```js
const app = new PIXI.Application({
  'antialias': true,
  'resolution': 2 // This may help too
});

// Add the view to the DOM
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

// ... your line code
```

The documentation for the `Application` class and its options can be found here:

https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Application.html

As a side note, PIXI is very fast but as your application scales anti-aliasing and resolution may have performance implications.

Finally to answer your question about what anti-aliasing is, in short, its a way to smooth out jagged edges on non-rectangular shapes, though you have a series lines it could help with your situation too. Here is an article that can tell you more: https://www.gamingscan.com/what-is-anti-aliasing/